# Orleans 7.0 GrainService registration

Tags: c#, orleans, .net-7.0

How should I register GrainService in Orleans 7.0?
I have GrainService:

```
    public interface IAlfaGrainService : IGrainService
    {
        Task<IReadOnlyList<AlfaData>> TestMethod();
    }

    [Reentrant]
    public class AlfaGrainService : GrainService, IAlfaGrainService
    {
        readonly IGrainFactory _grainFactory;
        private readonly ILogger<AlfaGrainService> logger;

        public AlfaGrainService(
            IServiceProvider services,
            Silo silo,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IGrainFactory grainFactory,
            ILogger<AlfaGrainService> logger)
            : base(GrainId.Create(nameof(AlfaGrainService), Guid.Empty.ToString()), silo, loggerFactory)
        {
            _grainFactory = grainFactory;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<AlfaData>> TestMethod()
        {
            logger.LogInformation("TestMethod() hit");
            // TODO: custom logic here.
            var data = new List<AlfaData> {
                new AlfaData
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Test 1"
                },
                new AlfaData
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Test 2"
                }
            };

            return await Task.FromResult(data);
        }
    }
```

GrainServiceClient (because I want to call GrainService from Grain):

```
    public interface IAlfaGrainServiceClient : IGrainServiceClient<IAlfaGrainService>, IAlfaGrainService
    {
    }

    public class AlfaGrainServiceClient : GrainServiceClient<IAlfaGrainService>, IAlfaGrainServiceClient
    {
        public AlfaGrainServiceClient(
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            : base(serviceProvider)
        { }

        public Task<IReadOnlyList<AlfaData>> TestMethod()
        {
            // Not sure how to get grainService reference:
            var grainId = GrainId.Create(nameof(AlfaGrainService), Guid.Empty.ToString());
            var service = GetGrainService(grainId);
            // -------------------------------------

            return service.TestMethod();
        }
    }
```

Grain from which I want to call GrainService (by proxy GrainServiceClient):

```
    public interface IAlfaGrain: IGrainWithStringKey
    {
        Task<IReadOnlyList<AlfaData>> LoadData();
    }

    public class AlfaGrain: Grain, IAlfaGrain
    {
        private readonly IAlfaGrainServiceClient alfaGrainServiceClient;

        public AlfaGrain(
            IAlfaGrainServiceClient alfaGrainServiceClient)
        {
            this.alfaGrainServiceClient = alfaGrainServiceClient;
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<AlfaData>> LoadData()
        {
            return await alfaGrainServiceClient.TestMethod();
        }
    }
```

But If I register GrainService like this:

```
    siloBuilder
    .AddGrainService<AlfaGrainService>()  // Register grainService like this ??
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IAlfaGrainServiceClient, AlfaGrainServiceClient>();
    });
```

I got error during starting app:

```
A suitable constructor for type 'GrainServiceApp.GrainServices.AlfaGrainService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.
```

Maybe because the GrainServiceFactory() (Orleans.Hosting.GrainServicesSiloBuilderExtensions) doesn't create instance with all ctor parameters.
[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/grains/grainservices) is only about prev version of Orleans and thus doesn't work in my case.

Does anybody know how register GrainService in Orleans 7.0?

All code is on [github](https://github.com/petr-kostelansky/orleans7-examples/tree/main/GrainServices/GrainServiceApp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already found the solution and it was quite simple.

1. I needed to inject **GrainId** into GrainService and pass it into the base class:

   ```
    public AlfaGrainService(
        GrainId grainId,
        Silo silo,
        IServiceProvider services,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ILogger<AlfaGrainService> logger)
        : base(grainId, silo, loggerFactory)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
   ```
2. Then in GrainServiceClient I got GrainService instance by **CurrentGrainReference.GrainId** like this:

   ```
    public Task<IReadOnlyList<AlfaData>> TestMethod()
    {
        var service = GetGrainService(CurrentGrainReference.GrainId);

        return service.TestMethod();
    }
   ```

I have updated the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/petr-kostelansky/orleans7-examples/tree/main/GrainServices/GrainServiceApp)